# How to use select with if in plsql

Tags: plsql

Im trying to print a message that tells you if a user exits or not in an employee table.

here is my code;

```
DECLARE
 empid  employees.employee_id%type := &id;

BEGIN
if empid IS NOT NULL Then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('user Exists');
elsif
if empid IS NULL Then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('User doesnt exist');
END;
/
```

it returns user exits even if it doesnt i test it using data i don,t know where to change or do i have use a select statement to select data

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Yes you need to use a select statement to select data, clearly.  All you are doing at the moment is confirming that the user has entered something for &id.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fill the variable from a select. Usually, it would work like this:

`select id into empid from emp where id = 1234`

But beware. If the ID doesn't exist, then you will get `ora-01403`. To select it into the variable using this method, there needs to be one record in the resultset. Therefore, rearrange the query like this to get back `null` if your ID doesn't exist:

`select (select id from emp where id = 1234) into empid from dual`

Comment: No point in the NVL is there?  Just `select (select id from emp where id = 1234) into empid from dual`.

Comment: Thank you i implemented the select nd i cn display if user exists. My problem is nw the non existing user. Must i use to selects and an if because i jst want 1 or the other printed nt both

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that.

Comment: Sorry thomas i meant must i use 2 selects because i want to display user if they exist and display a message if user doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

2 possible solutions:

```
DECLARE
 empid  employees.employee_id%type := &id;
 cnt integer;
BEGIN
 select count(*) into cnt from emp where id = empid;
 if cnt > 0 Then
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('user Exists');
 else
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('User doesnt exist');
 end if;
END;
/
```

Or if you want to get some information about the employee:

```
DECLARE
 empid  employees.employee_id%type := &id;
 empname employees.employee_name%type;
BEGIN
 select name into empname from employees where employee_id = empid;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('user Exists name='||empname);
EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('User doesnt exist');
END;
/
```